# 1 switch box- 4 wires

Tags: wiring

I took out a wall and had to move some wires.  I had to disconnect 2 light switches. I took a picture of one of the switches, a 2 way switch. The other switch I forgot to take a picture of. Well that box has 4 wires going into and no matter what configuration I use I cannot make it work right.

There is a 14/3 wire into the box. There is a 12/2 wire coming into it from the 3 way switch. There is a wire coming into it from the ceiling (I assume feeding 1 light and the microwave). And 1 more wire coming up from the floor which powers the light in the basement.

So the 2 way switch controls the ceiling light in kitchen. The single switch controls the light in the dining room. The others wires from that box feed 2 lights and a microwave.

I have the red wire on a brass screw. There is a black pigtail from the black screw. All the whites are together on one wire nut. I assume one of the 4 black wires goes on the other brass screw. I tried all 4. Various things happen depending on the wiring such as shutting off one light turns on another. (FYI The other 2 lights are controlled by single switches in different walls that I did not touch).  I am at a loss. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you get us photos of the inside of the box you are having trouble with?

Comment: Just added. Where the red arrow is there are 2 wires.

Comment: I'm no expert, but that box looks _way_ to tiny to have 4 cables in it

Comment: what you can't see is that the box expands to the left and right behind the wall. 1972 construction.